# Android screen brightness Max Value?

Tags: android, screen-brightness

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

I added this code to button onClick and it worked !
But is there a higher value since the screen didn't light MAX ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness), no. Setting `screenBrightness` to 1 should adjust the brightness to full light.

Comment: A nice way to use this is by using the constant `BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL`. Its value is 1.0f

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the value as 1L and it should go to max brightness as this is the max brightness

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

Will set it to max brightness..

Answer (score 0):

You should disable screen dimming first before you set the brightness, or you may get a less than MAX brightness ! Try something like this before you set the brightness:

```
// disable screen dimming (note - this also requires setting in manifest file)
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Use this code

```
float SysBackLightValue = 255f;


android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(BatteryBoosterActivity.this.getContentResolver(),   android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,(int) SysBackLightValue);                                    
Window myWindow =BatteryBoosterActivity.this. getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = myWindow.getAttributes();                                    winParams.screenBrightness = 255f;
myWindow.setAttributes(winParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

A full example shows how to change brightness by coding, foreground, background.
[brightnessdemo](https://github.com/XinyueZ/brightnessdemo)